# Identify the mold

Tags: identification, shrubs, mold

This dirt like thing is on much of my Skip Laurel. It’s a mold right? Can you help identify the mold, cause and remedy?

[image: front]
[image: underside]

Comment: Can you check beneath the leaves to see if there's anything there that shouldn't be - also the woody stems. You're looking for shield shaped objects on the stems, or fluffy white deposits under the leaves, or even small insects under the leaves.

Comment: Hi @Bamboo, updated. Don’t really see any of what you described

Comment: It looks like sooty mould, or sooty mould previously formed and dried out a bit - sooty mould is associated with heavy aphid or scale infestation. Does the black mould wash off if you try, or is it actually in the leaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooty mold is exactly what it is. Confirmed by someone who saw it live.